# Counting seconds since button pressed. Incorrect Interval, values not resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on counting the seconds since my `Move` button was pressed in my program. I have declared a global variable called `startTime` and neglected to set it's value until my `Move` button is pressed. After this I set the value to `0` and my program moves to my `moveBall()` funcion. In this function I declare: `startTime = setInterval(function(){startTime + 1;}, 1000);` then reset the value from `0` to the new value of `startTime`. After the `Stop` button is clicked I `clearInterval(startTime);`.

My problem is that my `startTime` value never resets to `0` if I stop the program and then start the program again. Also even though I declared the `setInterval` to go every 1000 milliseconds which should be a second. The `startTime` value seems to increase by 1 every millisecond.

Here are my relevant code portions, when my button with the id `move` is clicked:

```
$('#move').on('click', function(){
    //Reset the startTime to 0 everytime Move is pressed
    startTime = 0;
    $('#time').html(startTime);

    startGame = setInterval(function(){ moveBall();}, 20);
    //disable the 'move' button
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    //disable the 'Change Settings' button
    $('#change').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

When my button with the id `stop` is pressed:

```
  $('#stop').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(startGame);
    clearInterval(startTime);
    //enable the 'move' button
    $('#move').prop('disabled', false);
    //enable the 'Change Settings' button
    $('#change').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

And here is my moveBall function:

```
function moveBall(){
    //Starting the timer since moveBall() has begun
    startTime = setInterval(function(){ startTime + 1;}, 1000);
    $('#time').html(startTime);

    //read current top position
    var currentTop = parseInt($('#ball').css('top'));
    //read current left position
    var currentLeft = parseInt($('#ball').css('left'));

    /*If the top boundry of the ball is on or outside of the top border
        of the base then change the direction */
    if(currentTop + ball_radiusV > max_height || currentTop < 0){
        vx *= -1; //multiply dx by -1
    }

    /* If the right boundry of the ball is on or outside of the right border
        of the base then change the direction */
    if(currentLeft + ball_radiusH > max_width || currentLeft < 0){
        hx *= -1; //multiply dx by -1
    }

    //define new position 
    var newtop = currentTop + vx;
    var newLeft = currentLeft + hx;
    //change current position
    $('#ball').css('top', newtop + 'px');
    $('#ball').css('left', newLeft + 'px');
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ startTime + 1;}, 1000);` doesn't do anything useful. It adds 1 to a variable but the result is not used, nor stored.

Comment: I've changed it to `setInterval(function(){startTime+= 1;},1000);` and my value resets to `0` when the `stop` button is pressed then `move` is pressed again. It still adds `1` every millisecond instead of second though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your a mixing up the return value of setInterval.

setInterval returns an handle to the function scheduled, so you can call clearInterval().

From Mdn:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

```
Syntax
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
intervalID is a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval().
```

If you then call startTime + 1 in that function, what happens?
nothing is returned, startTime is not changed, is just evaluated and the function exit.

to count seconds passed, is an overkill to call a function every second and add 1, it will be also not precise probably.

Try to do like this:

```
when start button is pressed:
startTime = new Date().getTime();
```

when stop button is pressed:

```
millisecondsPassed = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
secondsPassed = Math.floor(millisecondPassed / 1000);
```

If the only meaning of the function is to increase time, you do not have to call it at all, no intervals to clear.

Comment: I've made some adjustments. I've declared a new global variable `newTime` and set it equal to `setInterval` like this. `newTime = setInterval(startTime += 1, 1000);` and when my `stop` button is clicked it will `clearInterval(newTime);`. I believe it is working correctly now.

Comment: So with that new time method will I use `setInterval`? @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: I need to show the seconds increasing as the ball moves. Not just when the user clicks stop is what I meant to say. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: I've figured it out. You can ignore the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns a reference to the interval you have just created, so that later you can stop the interval.

```
var myRef = setInterval(...);
clearInterval(myRef);
```

Every time `moveBall()` is called and you run this

```
startTime = setInterval(function(){ startTime + 1;}, 1000);
$('#time').html(startTime);
```

you are creating a new interval and outputting it's reference. In most browsers that is a simple counter that starts from 1. You should not modify the `startTime` value if you are planning on using later as you will have lost the reference value to your interval timer.